# Passing HTML tag data- to Django with form submit

Tags: django, forms, api, templates

I am trying to pass data in HTML tag with a form submit to Django

I currently have a template like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div class="product">
        {{ item.item_name }}
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    value="add to cart"
                    data-pk="{{item.pk}}"
                    class="add_product"/>
            <form>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to pass data-pk with a Django form. How do I do that?
Also I know, I can create a view to handle endpoint to do that, and include pk in the url, is that a better solution?

I am new to Django, and I will be grateful for any input on how to do stuff *the right way*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `data`, use `value={{item.pk}}` and handle the submit logic in your view.

Comment: EDIT: ok, just typed that in, and noticed, i already use value, to set the text of the submit button... can I have both?

Comment: change that `input` to a `button` and inside the `button` use `value` property to set the value. Eg. `<button type='submit' value='{{item.pk}}'>Add to cart</button>`

Comment: OK, I can do that